# Property 'ngRedux' does not exist on type 'AppModule'.?

Tags: angular, redux, react-redux, angular6

I have been working to implement redux in angular6 , Its almost completed The Application is working fine , but it throws an error in the node cli **Property  'ngRedux' does not exist on type 'AppModule'.?**

> When i add NgRedux in App.module.ts imports, and exports, It throws an error and application
>   stopped working.

Is There any fix ?

> My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgRedux, NgReduxModule } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';

import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

import { IAppState, rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE } from './reducers/rootReducers';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgReduxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatBadgeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 

      constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
      // ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
      this.ngRedux = ngRedux;
      ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, [ createLogger() ]);
      console.log(this.ngRedux.getState());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your app.module.ts code?

Comment: I have updated the question with app.module.ts @eduPeeth

Comment: It's a basic typescript error. Your constructor is doing `this.ngRedux = ...`. But you haven't declared any `ngRedux` property. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. That said, I don't know why you would be initializing such a property in the first place.

Comment: So i am a react developer , and learner of typescript how can we handle this , I need to use ngRedux in the  addtodo action that is the reason i have declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you are using `this.ngRedux`, as ngRedux is not declared as variable of class AppModule. Either remove `this` or declare as class variable like :

```
export class AppModule { 
ngRedux : NgRedux;
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    // ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
    this.ngRedux = ngRedux;
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE, [ createLogger() ]);
    console.log(this.ngRedux.getState());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks :) @eduPeeth